# How to Display Uploaded Documents in InfoPath Forms on DropdownList selected value?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

Hello I am new to InfoPath!
I have a ClientList which is bound to DropDownList. I want to display the Documents uploaded by Specific Client when DropdownList Value changes and accordingly the documents must be displayed in RepeaterTable or RepeaterSection in InfoPath.

Any Idea?
Help Appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a unique ID for the client, and that the documents for each client have a field with the respective client ID. Create a data connection to the library. Drag the data node onto the form to create a repeating table.

Create a rule on the client drop-down: when the value changes, set the client ID field in the query node in the secondary data source to the value of the drop-down, then query the data source.

Comment: Thanks for Replying @teylyn! I have both columns ClientName & ClientID in DocumentsList but the ClientID which is LookUp Field is not visible in DataConnection wizard. so how to make it visible in dataconnection?

Comment: Instead of the standard lookup field data connection you need to create a new data connection within InfoPath. That will allow you to select any column from the list/library.

Comment: Sorry to say but the Document is uploaded in Built in Sharepoint Library using Attach file option. So, how to get the Document Link and what type of control must be used to Display Documents of Selected Client from DropDownList!Plz clarify if i am wrong! Thanks!

Comment: You don't "attach" files to a document library. They are uploaded (or created from a content type). What you describe sounds more like a list, where a document is attached to a list item. That's a different story. If you want to manage documents, use a document library, not a list.

Comment: I am already storing the documents in document library itself with "RelatedClient" field having the lookup value from Client List to know who uploaded the Document. Now just i want to list in InfoPath Form when Populated DropDownList containing ClientNames the correspoding Client Document must be listed. Any Idea? Thanks

Comment: Can you start over? It seems you are contradicting yourself. Create a data connection to the document library. Use the field that the InfoPath form and the document library have in common to filter the document library. What is the problem?